# Computing $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{\tan(z)}{z e^{\frac{1}{z+2}}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Compute the integral for $z\in\mathbb{C}$: $$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{\tan(z)}{z e^{\frac{1}{z+2}}}$$

Inside the domain of $|z|=1$ the singular point I was able to detect was zero, however I do not know how to claissify it:

$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\tan(z)}{z e^{\frac{1}{z+2}}}$

If $x\in\mathbb{R}$ then using L'Hopital:$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan(x)}{x e^{\frac{1}{x+2}}}=\frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{2}}}$.
However I do not know how to proceed in the complex case.

I know by the  book solution that the integral equals $0$.

**Question**:

How should I compute the integral?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- $\tan z$ has simples poles at $\frac{\pi m}{2}i$ for odd integers $m$. All of them are outside the unit disc.
- $\frac1z$ has a simple pole at $z = 0$ but get cancelled by a zero of $\tan z$.
  This makes $z = 0$ a [removable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity) of the integrand.
- $e^{\frac{1}{z+2}}$ has an [essential singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity) at $z = -2$. Once again, it is outside the unit disc.

Combine them, we find there are no singularities that matter on or inside the disc. The integrand is holomorphic over the unit disc (in fact, over a larger disc $|z| < \frac{\pi}{2}$). By  [Cauchy integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_theorem), the integral over unit circle vanishes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In your second point: How did you compute the $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\tan(z)}{z e^{\frac{1}{z+2}}}$?

Comment: $\frac{\tan z}{z e^{1/(z+2)}} = \frac{\sin z}{z} \frac{1}{\cos z}\frac{1}{e^{1/(z+2)}}$ The last two factors are continuous and non-zero at $z = 0$, you can effectively take them out from the limit (and replace them by their value at $z = 0$). You are left with $\frac{\sin z}{z}$. Since $\sin(z) = z - \frac{z^3}{3!} + \cdots$, $\frac{\sin z}{z} = 1 - \frac{z^2}{2!} + \cdots$ is a converging power series at $z = 0$. This leads to $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sin z}{z} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $\frac {\sin\,x } x \to 1$ as $x\to 0$ in the real line is also true in the complex plane. Hence $\frac {\tan\,z } z \to 1$ as $z\to 0$ and the integrand has a removable singularity at $0$. By Cauchy's Theorem the integral is $0$.